# HANA showing 0 observations when pulling HANA table

Tags: r, jdbc, hana

I am having trouble querying HANA data in R. I have connected to many of our tables but this one is giving me problems.

When I connect through Tableau, it works fine. I am prompted with these variables. All except for companycode and the dates were prefilled.
[image]

In an attempt to get the data into R, I have this:

```
sql <- "SELECT * FROM \"cona-reporting.cam::Q_CA_R_LaborandMaterial\"(
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_CompanyCode$$', '4500'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ReferenceDateFrom$$', '2020-08-29'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ReferenceDateTo$$', '2020-09-02'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_IncludeOrderUserStatus$$', 'E0018 | ZCCSMCDE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExcludeOrderUserStatus$$', 'E0018 | ZCCSMCDE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_IncludeOrderSystemStatus$$', 'ALL'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExcludeOrderSystemStatus$$', 'NONE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_IncludeUserStatus$$', 'E0018 | ZCCSMCDE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExcludeUserStatus$$', 'E0018 | ZCCSMCDE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_IncludeSystemStatus$$', 'ALL'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$IP_ExcludeSystemStatus$$', 'NONE'),
            'PLACEHOLDER' = ('$$V_ValueType', '04'))"

repairtime <- dbGetQuery(jdbcConnection, sql)
```

Which returns a dataframe of 0 obs but all variables. Tableau shows me ~5000 observations. What's going on here?

Comment: Hard to say what’s going on without knowing the calculation view. A possible important difference is the format of the values with date semantics. In Tableau the values don’t include hyphens where in the code version they do. Try making all parameter values exactly the same first.

Comment: Tried both YYYMMDD and YYYY-MM-DD, neither did the trick. What is meant by the calculation view? I'm super bad with SAP lingo.

Comment: The "table" that you are trying to access in your query is in fact a view. In HANA there are different types of views, one of them being a "calculation view". The important bit here is that the design of this calculation view `Q_CA_R_LaborandMaterial` defines what happens with the `PLACEHOLDER` information. Some of those will be used to *filter* data and some of it may be *converted*, or used in *calculations*. E.g. filters like `"ALL"` or `"NONE"` are *not* HANA specific SQL conditions, but special values that the calc. view evaluates. So, you need to check what this calc. view does.

Comment: Going into the tableau sql view revealed the answer. companycode and several other parameters has triple quotes surrounding them. Bringing that into R pulled data. What is the significance of triple quotes?

Comment: It’s a form of escape string for strings that include quote chars.